# How to get value of href for any element in the dom having href attribute using simple_html_dom

Tags: java, php, codeigniter, simple-html-dom

IS it possible to get all the elements which has href as a attribute from the dom using simple_html_dom in php

and also get the value of that href ?

Comment: can you explain in more detail where you want the href data

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want to store an html page to memory, and then parse out all the hrefs in it?

Comment: store an html page to memory and get all the html elements with attribute as href

Comment: Not sure if you you can use simple_html for that(as i've neved used it), but regex might work.. find all that starts with href and ends with a space I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would do:

```
foreach($html->find('[href]') as $el){
  echo $el->href;
}
```